# 4 bit even odd parity checker/generator using logic gates only

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates, parity

Hi i am working on my digital electronics project 4-bit even odd parity generator and checker this is my circuit.how do i implement this on breadboard and what am i missing here except the vcc and where to place the led's to show even odd.
Thanks

[image: logic.ly]

Comment: You're missing proper input connections.

Comment: There's a pretty good schematic editor that you can use when modifying your question. I recommend you use it. I don't recommend your current schematic generator to anyone. The inputs look like toilets and the interconnects look like pipes. Are you sure this isn't some kind of plumbing/maintenance software you used by mistake?

Comment: http://logic.ly/demo/

Comment: You mentioned in a comment below that you can't use ICs.  Can you clarify?  What are you allowed to use then?

Comment: @Justin only logic gates,leds,resistors

Comment: @Franco - A logic gate is what aardash used in his answer.  If you're going to use a logic gate on a breadboard, you either need to use a logic gate IC or a combination of transistors.  But I don't see transistors on your list, so a logic gate IC is what you need. Is the issue that you don't want an IC with all 4 gates in a single package?

Comment: I AM SO CONFUSED RIGHT NOW, I'll change my project to even parity insted of both :P

Answer (score 1):

You wanna use IC 7486 quad xor gate.It has 4 xor gate in it.the pin diagram is like the first image.

  [image: xor gate]

Then the second picture describes you the breadboard connection

  [image: breadboard connection]

This is what exactly like your schematics.One think you have to remember on breadboard like this image.

  [image: breadboard]

If you wish to know the electrical circuit,here it is

  [image: basic electrical circuit]

.

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention we can't use ic's

Comment: It's actually almost difficult without IC's,But I'll pose you the basic electrical circuit which I found in my high school physics book.(only the xor gates electrical circuit).If you tell without IC,then there is no meaning for this site(electronics),anyway,I'll pose,may be it'll help .Hope.

Comment: May I know,for what application you going to use this schematics you posed above.Because in modern world,you can do thinks easier with IC chips.

Comment: As an aside: the "electrical circuit" shown on the right side of your textbook page for XOR is nonsensical.

Comment: It's like,you cant use a switch at a time to power two terminals.I know it'll be weird but without choice I posed this electric circuit @duskwuff.

Comment: @Aadarsh i am studying intro to digital logic so we are only allowed to use ic's for projects like ALU,digital clocks,digital dice e.t.c and it's just a project won't be needing this in model world :P it's just to understand how gates work.

Comment: Then I'll recommend you to know about DTL(diode transistor Logic) and TTL(transistor-transistor Logic) to understand the basics.So my next question is Are you familiar with the concepts of diodes and transistors?.If you know then you can understand the basics of logic gates very well :).The answer by Transistor is the one which describes DTL logic for xor gate. @Franco

Comment: You just need to know one thing about diode.In forward Bias,it conducts.In reverse bias,it blocks flow of current.For transistor,you should be familiar about cut-off region and saturation region(just  for Digital electronics,analog is more than that).

Answer (score 0):

There's are good examples at [homofaciens.de](http://www.homofaciens.de/technics-base-circuits-logic-gates_en_navion.htm) for each of the standard logic functions. XOR is one of the trickier ones to implement but it can be done like this.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXN3TJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**How it works**

***A and B low***: The output is low since there is no power through D1 or D3 to drive the output high.

***A high - B low***: Output will be high because 'A' will feed the OUT terminal through D1. D4 will pull Q1's gate low turning off Q1 preventing it from pulling OUT low.

***A low - B high***: Output also high by same logic as previous example.

***A high - B high***: Output low. Even though the left side of R3 is high the right side will be pulled low by Q1 because the gate is pulled high by R1.

You could make this into a four or five (or any number) input gate by adding more diode pairs.

Calculating the component values is left to the OP.

Comment: can't add diodes , it's a project for digital logic and design

Comment: Then why did you tell Aadarsh that you can't use ICs? Please fix your original question rather than reply in a comment.